# iOS App stuck on sharing action sheet when WhatsApp is not logged in

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

When I tried to shared a link to WhatsApp using `UIActivityViewController`, the app is stuck at the share sheet. I have to quit and relaunch the app to use again.
Is there anyway I can check if the WhatsApp is currently logged in.?

```
let shareActivity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareableUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
    shareActivity.excludedActivityTypes = [.assignToContact, .markupAsPDF, .openInIBooks, .print, .saveToCameraRoll]
    self.present(shareActivity, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When WhatsApp is logged in no issue.
Also the `shareActivity.completionWithItemsHandler` is not being called as probably the sharing is not complete (I tired to use strong reference as well).

Thanks in advance